# creating checkbox

Tags: delphi

I am trying to create a few checkboxes, how many is decided by the recordcount of a query. Also i need to set the loction of the check box +38 from the previous location.  Anyone give me some help with this? not sure how to create the checkboxes, The rest i should be able to do...anyhow he is what i have so far.

```
var
  i, top,left : integer;
begin
......
    left := 81;
    top := 119;
    while i < qry.RecordCount do
                  begin
                    // create check box
                    // set caption of checkbox to i
                    // set checkbox loction to left + 38, top
                    // left = left+38??
                  end;
```

Comment: why not just use CheckListBox component ?

Comment: Is Query a TDataSet? In that case it might be better to use the `while not qry.EoF do qry.Next` pattern.

Comment: Or even better: Use somehing like a `TcxDBCheckListBox` from DevExpress.

Comment: or JediVCL - it is much less expensive and code is much more simple usually :-)

Comment: @Arioch apart from the epic dependencies

Comment: @DavidHeffernan On dependencies i don't see much difference. Except that JCL/JVCL come with build script and for DevEx you have to re-create it manually, if would modify its sources. Other than that, both DX and JCL/JVCL consist of set of packages. That you would care about if u deploy with stock BPLs. Or you completely ignore whether you deploy monolythic exe or your own monolithic all-widgets BPL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After clarifying your needs, I would recommend you to use [`TObjectList`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Contnrs.TObjectList) as a container for your check boxes. This list can own the objects, what allows you to release them by a simple removing the item from the list either by [`Clear`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.TList.Clear) or by [`Delete`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.TList.Delete). It also provides a simple access to each element by typecasting the obtained indexed item object to your known class type. More in the following untested pseudo-code:

```
uses
  Contnrs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    CheckList: TObjectList;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CheckList := TObjectList.Create;
  // setting OwnsObjects to True will ensure you, that the objects
  // stored in a list will be freed when you delete them from list
  CheckList.OwnsObjects := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // this will also release all check boxes thanks to OwnsObjects
  CheckList.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  CheckBox: TCheckBox;
begin
  ...
  CheckList.Clear;                      // this will free all check boxes    
  for I := 0 to RecordCount - 1 do      // iterate over your recordset
  begin
    CheckBox := TCheckBox.Create(nil);  // be sure to use nil as an owner
    CheckBox.Parent := Self;            // where will be laying (Self = Form)
    CheckBox.Caption := IntToStr(I);    // caption by the iterator value
    CheckBox.Top := 8;                  // fixed top position
    CheckBox.Left := (I * 38) + 8;      // iterator value * 38 shifted by 8
    CheckBox.Width := 30;               // fixed width
    CheckList.Add(CheckBox);            // add the check box to the list
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // this will check the first check box from the list (be careful to indexes)
  TCheckBox(CheckList.Items[0]).Checked := True;
  // this will delete 3rd check box from the list (using Clear will delete all)
  CheckList.Delete(2);
end;
```

Comment: Nice, but how to destroy objects when we wont to do this?

Comment: nice, but yes now i think about it i will need that.. maybe another question :D  but when i change value on combobox it should delete all of them.  but will try this

Comment: P.S. without knowing your Delphi version I can't suggest you to use generics way (and find that is for me quite hard this time since my mouse decided to die and I'm llame using a touchpad :-)

Comment: TList<TCheckBox> would be much better

Comment: @David, I've been waiting for you to say this :-) That's why I've mentioned the note about missing Delphi version and, more natural would be `TObjectList<TCheckBox>`.

Answer (score 5):

Your pseudo code translates almost literally into Delphi code although it's better to use a `for` loop here:

```
for I := 0 to qry.RecordCount-1 do
  begin
  CheckBox := TCheckBox.Create (Self);            // the form owns the checkbox
  CheckBox.Parent := Self;                        // checkbox is displayed on the form
  CheckBox.Caption := IntToStr (I);
  CheckBox.Top := Top;
  CheckBox.Left := 81 + I*38;
  end;
```

BTW, you don't have to free the created checkbox thanks to the ownership mechanism built into the VCL.

Comment: This could be extended by using a container (like `TPanel`) as a common parent. This way recreating the TCheckBoxes on some event is possible withoug using a TObjectList.

Comment: @Jens, yeah that's much easier... I would even upvote this post when there won't be the overcomplicated use of `Left` variable.

Comment: using single CheckListBox component is harder than creatig by hands ? The only thign that would be real hard is forcing that 38 px margin. All the rest would be CheckListBox1.Items.Text := string-of-names ;-)

Comment: Now you got my upvote :-) Interesting; I feel that less effort you give to the answer higher score you got and vice-versa. I will have to rethink my participation here...

Comment: @TLama I don't think that is true. Maybe a more verbose answer sometimes makes the core of the answer harder to see. And some people might not try to read and understand a longer answer. Keep up your effort and participation please!

Comment: @Smasher, but i do think. People do not want to learn, do not want to think, and obviously don't want to hear "you're doing it wrong".
They have feelings for their solutions, they want "fix it for me" rather than "refactor it for me". The scores are objective measure, and they suggest it.

Comment: Why are you so negative today? There are plenty of people here willing to learn and thankful for your help...

Comment: @Smasher 1st i am not TLama :-)
Second - by just observing which comments and answers are rewarded and which are not. Those people are either not plenty but minority (which should be natural assumption: such people would probably find their answers themselves, not frequently going to SO-like sites). Or - if you insist on their vast numbers on SO, that would mean they do not tip those comments they like. I prefer "not quite plenty" interpretation :-)

Comment: i disagree, i use SO quite alot, either to get an understanding of how to do something(if you never did it something easy can be confusing even with documents on the web) and second to improve a part of code. I may know how to do it, but want to see if there is a better way. I think both answers here are good and work, but I choose the one i did cause its more independent and a better way "FOR ME" .  I cant speak for everyone else, and either should you :P